# Matlab optimisation - solver choice

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to minimize the following function and with the many choices of solvers in Matlab I would like to ask for your advice.
The basic function looks like the following:
M and Opratio are both single values, M should run between 0 and 10^7 (steps of 10000 are sufficient) and OPratio between 0 and 1.

```
 function NPVtotal = cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio)
 few hundred lines script
 end
```

The function for the optimisation is used for is an iterative optimisation problem itself. It loads and processes data in order to find a specific operating point for the operation. M and OPratio are basically input variables for the iterative process and they could be adapted for the operation if enough extra value is created. Hence I would like to find the optimum values for M and OPratio. Each iteration of the code takes roughly 40 seconds, therefore I would like to use an optimiser algorithm instead of writing a double iterative process for those two variables.
I hope this is a bit clearer definition. If any other information is needed for your help please let me know.

Comment: can you recommend any solver ?

Comment: Well, if you figured out that MATLAB only minimizes, you must have had a look at a few options. If not you must not have looked a lot. For now this question is way too broad

Comment: well if i try to get the function into negative like this: function -(NPVtotal = cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio)), i get "Unexpected MATLAB operator." for the minus

Comment: You need to add a minus on the last line where you modify `NPVtotal` in your function

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ... as you said my question regarding a solver is too broad - what kind of information is necessary to make it a "proper" question ? ... I will give my best :)

Comment: Well, first of all the choice for a solver will depend a lot on the specific problem you have. Is it constrained? (Here it is constrained by the bounds on your parameter values, but maybe you have other constraints). What are the sizes of your input/output variables? Can you explain a bit (without posting the whole code), what your code does, because maybe there would be analytical ways of solving it. That would already be a good start

Comment: i edited the post - i hope this is more helpful ... i will gladly answer all more information you need

Comment: It's already better. Have a look at http://fr.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/constrained-minimization-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html , which should work pretty well for your problem (It's pretty well documented, and the example explains all you need to do in order for it to work). If you encounter problems after trying it, please ask a new question and add a link to it in this one